# ODBC DSN connection Error (SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

Tags: sql-server, odbc, readonly, dsn, sql-server-native-client

I am trying to create a 64 bit DSN connection to connect with SQL Server.
Below are the configuration that I am making (Keeping rest of the settings to default):

```
Server: a_sql_server
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Application intent: READONLY
```

I am getting below error while testing the connection:

```
Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Encryption not supported on the client.
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SSL Provider: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Client unable to establish connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

TESTS FAILED!
```

Please note that I was able to successfully test the same configuration in another machine.

Any help/information is highly appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server Native Client 11.0 should not be used in any new development, it hasn't received any feature updates since SQL Server 2012. Consider switching to one of the current [ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows) versions.